# Is it possible to put an editorconfig file not at the top level root dir?

Tags: configuration, config, text-editor, atom-editor, editorconfig

So I have an editorconfig file like this:

```
# Indent preferences
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

# Do not change these
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
|-- src
|-- tools
|-- test
|-- config
    .editorconfig
```

As you can see, I have a config dir where I would like to keep all configuration related stuff. I would like the `.editorconfig` file there to be used across the entire project, but obviously it's not in the top-level root dir. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is impossible: `.editorconfig` files are loaded from root to the directory of the file on each directory level. Supporting such a feature in a `config` directory would easily mess things up.

Comment: @LEO EditorConfig mainly targets at defining the same coding style for a PROJECT, while allowing developers to use DIFFERENT editors. If it's a personal editor configuration, you can just do it in your editor settings.